# NextAuth.js (v5) - Is there a way to obtain the jwt at every callback call?

Tags: next.js, cookies, access-token, next-auth

I'm using `Auth.js` (v5) to implement authentication and authorization in a `Next.js` web app

I need to interact with the Identity Provider's API in endpoints that require the access token, so I wrote the callbacks in the following way

```js
export const {
    handlers,
    auth,
    signIn,
    signOut
} = NextAuth({
    providers: [Spotify],
    debug: true,
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    callbacks: {
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            if (session?.user && token.sub) {
                session.user.id = token.sub;
            }
            return {...session, access_token: token.accessToken};
        },
        jwt: async ({ user, token, account }) => {
            if (user) {
                token.uid = user.id;
            }
            if(account) {
                token.access_token = account.access_token
            }
            return token;
        },
    }
})
```

The issue is that `account` in the `jwt` callback is not `undefined` only when signing in. Do I need to save the access token in a cookie or is there a way to ensure that `account` is passed?